# How to make a controller's method unavailable to Codeigniter's previous_url()

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, http-headers, codeigniter-4

I am dynamically generating a javascript file on my script in a controller method and adding this dynamically generated script in my html just like you would a regular javascript.

In my php code I return

```
return $this->response
    ->setBody($data)
    ->setHeader('text/javascript')
    ->noCache()
    ->getBody();
```

`$data` is a variable that holds the data on the generated javascript file.
So far everything works well until I want to use codeigniter's built in `previous_url()` function then I'm taken to this javascript file file instead of the previous web page.

So far I have tried hacking the CI core and it works. What I did was `return false` in `storePreviousURL()` method of Codeigniter.php if the `Cache-control` response header contains the `no-cache` or `no-store` value which I'm setting with the built in CI `$response->no_cache()` method in the generator script.

What I want to know is if there is a better way to go around this as personally I also advice against hacking the core, but it seems I'm out of options here.

Comment: Why not simply `echo $data` between a `<script>` tag in your view instead of generating a file?

Comment: I could do that, but the file is generated in a controller and depends on many other components I won't want to bring into my views, I'm trying to make my code look as clean as possible.

Comment: with `echo $data`

Comment: The question is not about echoing the string result, how do I prevent php from storing the url to my generated script tag in $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], without having to hack the codeigniter core, since its in a script tags it should not be treated as a visited link, I can echo the results but I don't want to.

Comment: IMHO sometimes a core hack is worth it - its the great thing about PHP / CI - we have access to it if something isn't working. My advice - log what changes you make though so if you update to a newer version of CI you'll know what you need to re-code.

Comment: Thanks @Antony just what I needed to hear

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem, where I had created an image server to serve dynamic sized thumbnails and then that image url would become the *previous url* for anything that later needed it. For now I am using the recommended way to change the workings of core, without actually changing the core code: by using **Events**. It seems to have solved the problem.

I have added this code inside the method that serves the file:

```
$prevurl=previous_url(); //a function from the url helper
\CodeIgniter\Events\Events::on('post_system',function() use ($prevurl){
    \Config\Services::codeigniter()->storePreviousURL(\Config\Services::uri($prevurl,false));
});
```

This resets the *previous url* to whatever it was before calling this method (i.e., before requesting this url).

Comment: Is the post_system event a default system event or one you are propagating and when is it fired?

Comment: @3m1n3n3 It is a default system event. Its documentation can be found here: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/extending/events.html#event-points